# Printing list elements and strings in Python have different results

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a `.csv` file which is encoded in `UTF-8`.
I am working with Python `2.7`.
Something intereseting happens on `Ubuntu`.
When I print out the results of the file like this:

```
with open("file.csv", "r") as file:
    myFile = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ",")
    for row in myFile:
        print row
```

I get signs like `\xc3\x`, `\xa1\`, .... Note that `row` is a list and all the elements in my list are marked as strings by `''` in the output.
When I print out the results like this:

```
with open("file.csv", "r") as file:
    myFile = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ",")
    for row in myFile:
        print ",".join(row)
```

Everything is decoded fine. Note that every row from my original file is one big string here.

Why is that?

Comment: That's probably because if you print a list like this: `print ['åäö']` python will keep the internal encoding of the string as-is. Where as if you print `print ['åäö'][0]` it will try to decode/encode (can never remember which it is) to whatever encoding you've defined at the top of your script (Usually 7 or 8bit ASCII).

Comment: Also `join()` expects strings. Strings and bytes are the same thing in Python 2.7. In Python 3 this is not the case so i am guessing you wouldn't see that there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in the case of printing a list, Python is using `repr()`, but when printing a string it is using `str()`.  Example:

```
unicode_str = 'åäö'
unicode_str_list = [unicode_str, unicode_str]
print 'unwrapped:', unicode_str
print 'in list:', unicode_str_list
print 'repr:', repr(unicode_str)
print 'str:', str(unicode_str)
```

Produces:

```
unwrapped: åäö
in list: ['\xc3\xa5\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6', '\xc3\xa5\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6']
repr: '\xc3\xa5\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6'
str: åäö
```